# Double nesting in the tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

Using the [examples](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) from Wickhams introduction to purrr in R for data science, I am trying to create a double nested list.

```
library(gapminder)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
gapminder
nest_data <- gapminder %>% group_by(continent) %>% nest(.key = by_continent)
```

How can I further nest the countries so that nest_data contains by_continent and a new level of nesting by_contry that ultimately includes the tibble by_year?

Furthermore, after creating this datastructure for the gapminder data - how would you run the regression model examples from the [bookchapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) for each country?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply nest after grouping by both continent and country?  That seems like it would be more straightforward to work with.  If you really want the nested list columns, how about `nest_data %>% mutate(by_continent = map(by_continent, ~.x %>% group_by(country) %>% nest(.key = by_country)))`?

Comment: Appreciate your help. The structure is just a matter of trying to understand the list columns. Your command worked like a charm. However, I'm uncertain as to if I understand why. I tried something similar, but with just ~. instead of ~.x . What does the x do? Furthermore, If I now want to run a regression for each and every country without resorting to unnesting  and have the result in by_country how can that be done?

Comment: I've seen both `.` and `.x` used in `map`, but I usually use `.x` because that's what is in the documentation.  Maybe the `.` is confused here due to the `mutate` wrapper?  In terms of models by country from nested tibbles in columns, things got messy fast.  I got to `mutate(nested_again, models = map(by_continent, "by_country") %>% at_depth(2, ~lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = .x)))`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution with some explanation below.

```
library(gapminder)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

nest_data <- gapminder %>% group_by(continent) %>% nest(.key = by_continent)
```

### First question was: how to nest by_country inside the nested by_continent

#### Great solution by @aosmith on the comments

```
nested_again<-
nest_data %>% mutate(by_continent = map(by_continent, ~.x %>% 
                                          group_by(country) %>% 
                                          nest(.key = by_country)))
# Level 1
nested_again
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
# continent      by_continent
# <fctr>            <list>
#   1      Asia <tibble [33 × 2]>
#   2    Europe <tibble [30 × 2]>
#   3    Africa <tibble [52 × 2]>
#   4  Americas <tibble [25 × 2]>
#   5   Oceania  <tibble [2 × 2]>

# Level 2
nested_again %>% unnest %>% slice(1:2)
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
# continent     country        by_country
# <fctr>      <fctr>            <list>
#   1      Asia Afghanistan <tibble [12 × 4]>
#   2      Asia     Bahrain <tibble [12 × 4]>
```

### Second question: how to apply a regression model at a deeper level *(and save the models on the tibble, I suppose)*

#### Solution by @aosmith (which I'm calling sol1)

```
sol1<-mutate(nested_again, models = map(by_continent, "by_country") %>%
         at_depth(2, ~lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = .x)))

sol1
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
# continent      by_continent      models
# <fctr>            <list>      <list>
#   1      Asia <tibble [33 × 2]> <list [33]>
#   2    Europe <tibble [30 × 2]> <list [30]>
#   3    Africa <tibble [52 × 2]> <list [52]>
#   4  Americas <tibble [25 × 2]> <list [25]>
#   5   Oceania  <tibble [2 × 2]>  <list [2]>

sol1 %>% unnest(models)
# Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [models]
sol1 %>% unnest(by_continent) %>% slice(1:2)
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   continent     country        by_country
#      <fctr>      <fctr>            <list>
# 1      Asia Afghanistan <tibble [12 × 4]>
# 2      Asia     Bahrain <tibble [12 × 4]>
```

The solution is doing what it is supposed to, but there's no easy way to filter by country, because that information is nested in the level 2.

I propose the solution 2, based on @aosmith's solution to the first question:

```
sol2<-nested_again %>% mutate(by_continent = map(by_continent, ~.x %>% 
                  mutate(models = map(by_country, ~lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = .x) )) ))
sol2
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   continent      by_continent
#      <fctr>            <list>
# 1      Asia <tibble [33 × 4]>
# 2    Europe <tibble [30 × 4]>
# 3    Africa <tibble [52 × 4]>
# 4  Americas <tibble [25 × 4]>
# 5   Oceania  <tibble [2 × 4]>

sol2 %>% unnest %>% slice(1:2)
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   continent     country        by_country   models
#      <fctr>      <fctr>            <list>   <list>
# 1      Asia Afghanistan <tibble [12 × 4]> <S3: lm>
# 2      Asia     Bahrain <tibble [12 × 4]> <S3: lm>

sol2 %>% unnest %>% unnest(by_country) %>% colnames
# [1] "continent" "country"   "year"      "lifeExp"   "pop"      
# [6] "gdpPercap"

# get model by specific country
sol2 %>% unnest %>% filter(country == "Brazil") %$% models %>% extract2(1)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = lifeExp ~ year, data = .x)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)         year  
# -709.9427       0.3901

# summary with broom::tidy
sol2 %>% unnest %>% filter(country == "Brazil") %$% models %>%
  extract2(1) %>% tidy
#          term     estimate    std.error statistic      p.value
# 1 (Intercept) -709.9426860 10.801042821 -65.72909 1.617791e-14
# 2        year    0.3900895  0.005456243  71.49417 6.990433e-15
```

We can tidy all the models and save in the data to use for plotting or filter

```
sol2 %<>% mutate(by_continent = map(by_continent, ~.x %>% 
        mutate(tidymodels = map(models, tidy )) ))

sol2 %>% unnest %>% unnest(tidymodels) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(country,p.value,colour=continent))+geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~continent)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image: Linear model p-value by country]

```
selc <- sol2 %>% unnest %>% unnest(tidymodels) %>% filter(p.value > 0.05) %>% 
  select(country) %>% unique %>% extract2(1)

gapminder %>% filter(country %in% selc ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year,lifeExp,colour=continent))+geom_line(aes(group=country))+
  facet_wrap(~continent)
```

[image: Filtered by p-value]

aaaaand, we can use the models

```
m1 <- sol2 %>% unnest %>% slice(1) %$% models %>% extract2(1)

x <- sol2 %>% unnest %>% slice(1) %>% unnest(by_country) %>% select(year)

pred1 <- data.frame(year = x, lifeExp = predict.lm(m1,x))

sol2 %>% unnest %>% slice(1) %>% unnest(by_country) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, lifeExp )) + geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=pred1)
```

[image: using a model to predict]

In this case there's really no good reason to use this double nesting (besides learning how to to it, of course), but I found a case in my work where it is extremely valuable, specifically when you need a function to work on a 3rd level, grouped by levels 1 and 2, and save in level 2 - of course for this we could also use a `for` loop on level 1, but what's the fun in that ;) I'm not really sure how this "nested" `map` performs compared to `for` loop + `map`, but I'll test it next.

### Benchmark

It looks like they do not differ much

```
# comparison map_map with for_map
map_map<-function(nested_again){
nested_again %>% mutate(by_continent = map(by_continent, ~.x %>% 
  mutate(models = map(by_country, ~lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = .x) )) )) }

for_map<-function(nested_again){ for(i in 1:length(nested_again[[1]])){
  nested_again$by_continent[[i]] %<>%
  mutate(models = map(by_country, ~lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = .x) )) }}

res<-microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  mm<-map_map(nested_again), fm<-for_map(nested_again) )

res
# Unit: milliseconds
#                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  mm <- map_map(nested_again) 121.0033 144.5530 160.6785 155.2389 174.2915 240.2012   100   a
#  fm <- for_map(nested_again) 131.4312 148.3329 164.7097 157.6589 173.6480 455.7862   100   a

autoplot(res)
```

[image]