# accessing nested lists in R

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I have created a double nested structure for some data. How can I Access the data on the 2nd Level ( or for that matter the nth Level?)

```
library(gapminder)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
gapminder
nest_data <- gapminder %>% group_by(continent) %>% nest(.key = by_continent) 

nest_2<-nest_data %>% mutate(by_continent = map(by_continent, ~.x %>% group_by(country) %>% nest(.key = by_country)))
```

How can I now get the data for China into a dataframe or tibble from nest_2?

I can get the data for all of Asia, but I'm unable to isolate China.

```
a<-nest_2[nest_2$continent=="Asia",]$by_continent  ##Any better way of isolating Asia from nest_2?
```

I thought I could then do

```
b<-a[a$country=="China",]$by_country
```

But I get the following error

```
Error in a[a$country == "China", ] : incorrect number of dimensions 



> glimpse(a)
List of 1
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   33 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ country   : Factor w/ 142 levels "Afghanistan",..: 1 8 9 19 25 56 59 60 61 62 ...
  ..$ by_country:List of 33
```

So my big error was not recognizing that the product was a list, which could be remedied by adding [[1]] in the end. However, I very much liked the solution by @Floo0. I took the liberty of providing a function taking the names of the variables in case the sequence of columns are different from the one provided.

```
select_unnest <- function(df, listcol, var, var_val){  ###listcol, var and var_val must enclosed by ""
  df[[listcol]][df[[var]]==var_val][[1]]
}

nest_2 %>% select_unnest(listcol = "by_continent", var = "continent", var_val = "Asia") %>% 
  select_unnest(listcol = "by_country", var = "country", var_val = "China")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pipe-able (`%>%`) base R approach

```
select_unnest <- function(x, select_val){
  x[[2]][x[[1]]==select_val][[1]]
}

nest_2 %>% select_unnest("Asia") %>% select_unnest("China")
```

Comparing the timings:

```
Unit: microseconds

                min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
aosmith1   3202.105 3354.0055 4045.9602 3612.126 4179.9610 17119.495   100
aosmith2   5797.744 6191.9380 7327.6619 6716.445 7662.6415 24245.779   100
Floo0       227.169  303.3280  414.3779  346.135  400.6735  4804.500   100
Ben Bolker  622.267  720.6015  852.9727  775.172  875.5985  1942.495   100
```

Code:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  {a<-nest_2[nest_2$continent=="Asia",]$by_continent
  flatten_df(a) %>%
    filter(country == "China") %>%
    unnest},
  {nest_2 %>%
      filter(continent == "Asia") %>%
      select(by_continent) %>%
      unnest%>%
      filter(country == "China") %>%
      unnest},
  {nest_2 %>% select_unnest("Asia") %>% select_unnest("China")},
  {n1 <- nest_2$by_continent[nest_2$continent=="Asia"][[1]]
  n2 <- n1 %>% filter(country=="China")
  n2$by_country[[1]]}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `a` is still a list, which would need to be flattened before you could do more.

You could use `flatten_df`, `dplyr::filter`, and `unnest`:

```
library(dplyr)

flatten_df(a) %>%
    filter(country == "China") %>%
    unnest

# A tibble: 12 x 5
   country  year  lifeExp        pop gdpPercap
    <fctr> <int>    <dbl>      <int>     <dbl>
1    China  1952 44.00000  556263527  400.4486
2    China  1957 50.54896  637408000  575.9870
3    China  1962 44.50136  665770000  487.6740
4    China  1967 58.38112  754550000  612.7057
5    China  1972 63.11888  862030000  676.9001
6    China  1977 63.96736  943455000  741.2375
7    China  1982 65.52500 1000281000  962.4214
8    China  1987 67.27400 1084035000 1378.9040
9    China  1992 68.69000 1164970000 1655.7842
10   China  1997 70.42600 1230075000 2289.2341
11   China  2002 72.02800 1280400000 3119.2809
12   China  2007 72.96100 1318683096 4959.1149
```

An alternative way to pull out Asia and end up in a situation where you aren't working with a list.  This would avoid the need to `flatten` later.

```
asia = nest_2 %>%
    filter(continent == "Asia") %>%
    select(by_continent) %>%
    unnest
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `purrr` so don't quite understand how you ended up with something this weird/deeply nested (it seems you're following a similar approach to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228502/double-nesting-in-the-tidyverse?rq=1); the comments addressed to that question suggest some alternative approaches).  I can extract the tibble for China this way, but there must be a better way to do what you're trying to do ...

```
n1 <- nest_2$by_continent[nest_2$continent=="Asia"][[1]]
n2 <- n1 %>% filter(country=="China")
n2$by_country[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A data.table solution:

```
DT <- as.data.table(gapminder)

#nest data (starting smallest and working up):
nest_DT <- DT[, list(by_country = list(.SD)), by = .(continent, country)]
nest_2 <- nest_DT[, list(by_continent = list(.SD)), by = .(continent)]
```

We can now chain together calls of the form `[filter, column][[1]]` to get at the nested values

```
nest_2[continent == "Asia", by_continent][[1]]
               country   by_country
 1:        Afghanistan <data.table>
 2:            Bahrain <data.table>
 3:         Bangladesh <data.table>
 4:           Cambodia <data.table>
 5:              China <data.table>
 6:   Hong Kong, China <data.table>
 7:              India <data.table>
 8:          Indonesia <data.table>
 9:               Iran <data.table>
10:               Iraq <data.table>
11:             Israel <data.table>
12:              Japan <data.table>
...                ...          ...

nest_2[continent == "Asia", by_continent][[1]][country == "China", by_country][[1]]

    year  lifeExp        pop gdpPercap
 1: 1952 44.00000  556263527  400.4486
 2: 1957 50.54896  637408000  575.9870
 3: 1962 44.50136  665770000  487.6740
 4: 1967 58.38112  754550000  612.7057
 5: 1972 63.11888  862030000  676.9001
 6: 1977 63.96736  943455000  741.2375
 7: 1982 65.52500 1000281000  962.4214
 8: 1987 67.27400 1084035000 1378.9040
 9: 1992 68.69000 1164970000 1655.7842
10: 1997 70.42600 1230075000 2289.2341
11: 2002 72.02800 1280400000 3119.2809
12: 2007 72.96100 1318683096 4959.1149
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is [[]] operator instead of simple single [].

Comment: Nope  b<-a[[a$country=="China",]]$by_country 
Error in a[[a$country == "China", ]] : incorrect number of subscripts