# How can I access data in a nested R list?

Tags: r, list, indexing, nested

I want to learn how to access data from a nested list in R. I am relatively new to the R programming language, so I am unsure how to proceed.
The data is a 'large list(947 elements, 654.9mb) and takes the form:
[image]

The numbers within the datalist refer to station numbers and when I click on one (in Rstudio) it looks like this:
[image]

I want to kow how I can access the data within 'doy' for example. I have tried:

```
data[[1]]
```

which returns all the data for the first element of the list (site, location, doy,ltm etc). So clearly the number used within the square brackets is interpreted as an index for the list, as opposed to an identifier for the elements/station in the list.
Then I tried:

```
data$1
```

but it returned the error:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "data$1"
```

Then I tried:

```
data[data$1==doy]
```

But was returned this:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "data[data$1"
```

So at this point, I realise that it is not construing the number of the station as a category/factor within the list. It's just reading it as a number. So I thought I'd put some quotes around it to see if that changed what happened:

```
data[data$"1"=="doy"]
```

This returned

```
named list()
```

But when I looked at it in the environment, it was a list of 0.
I looked at some of the similar question here on Stack (like: [accessing nested lists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291360/accessing-nested-lists-in-r)) and tried:

```
data[data$"1"=="doy",][[1]]
```

But just got:

```
Error in data[data$"1" == "doy", ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

How can I access this data? It reminds me of a structure in Matlab, but it doesn't seem to be indexed in a similar fashion in R.

Comment: perhaps just try data[[1]]$doi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at some ways to do what you want:

```
data[[1]]
```

This returns the first element of the list, which is itself a list. You can use the `$` subsetting shorthand, but the name of the first element is nonstandard. R prefers names that start with letters and include only alphanumeric characters, periods and underscores. You can escape this behavior with backticks:

```
data$`1`
```

If you want to access one of the elements of list `1` in your list of lists, you need to further subset. To get to `doy`, which is the third element of `1`. You can do that four ways.

```
data[[1]][[3]]
data$`1`[[3]]
data[[1]]$doy
data$`1`$doy
```

Comment: Many thanks for all the different options! The backtick is brilliant for dealing with the nonstandard element names.

Comment: As an add on, is there a way to skip a level in the list? For example, `data[[,]]$doy` to get all the 'doy' datapoints for every station number/element? I get this error when I try the above: `Error in data[[, ]] : incorrect number of subscripts`.

Comment: You could use `lapply` to do this. You will get a list back: `lapply(1:length(data), function(x) data[[x]]$doy)`.

Answer (score 2):

One way (in addition to what Ben Norris has shown):

```
our_list[[c("1", "doy")]]
```

Reproducible example data (please provide next time)

```
our_list <- list(`1` = list(site = "x", doy = 3))
```